# How to apply Alpha to a collection with all the objects within the collection

Tags: transparency, collections

I have multiple objects with various textures and materials, in different collections. Is it possible to apply an Alpha to the collection itself with the objects inside it? So I can control how much of the collection is visible in the viewport?

As an example, I'm posting a screenshot from Photoshop, which has a group with 4 different layers, and I can control the opacity of the group from 0 to 100.

[image]

And here's a Blender screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems impossible at the moment. Even on the design/idea level, collections are not like layer folders in Photoshop, an object can belong to multiple collections, so it's not clear what the behavior should be in such a case:

[image]

If you added a custom property `alpha` to each collection, and a custom property `1st_col_alpha` to each object, you could then add a driver to the latter:

```py
self.original.users_collection[0]['alpha']
```

Which would use the insecure Python (need to enable script autoexecution, read about the security considerations [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243271/60486)) to copy the first collection's alpha to self alpha, which then can be accessed in the shader this way:

[image]

Unfortunately this has a problem with refreshing, changing the collection property doesn't automatically refresh the driver. There are various ways to fix it, one would be to simply force a refresh each frame by modifying the driver this way:

```py
self.original.users_collection[0]['alpha'] + 0*frame
```

[image]

Comment: Seems impressive technique, very much out of my league this type of method, I have no experience in this field in Blender with code, or drivers, too complicated for me to know even where to start. Maybe in the future a Blender release could include something like Photoshop to target the collections Alpha. Thank you for your reply.