# driver not working

Tags: python, drivers

I want to use the folowing driver:

```
abs(((frame+45) % 90)-45)
```

But it does nothing. I tried also `#abs` and `#frame` etc. But nothing, the thing is purple as expected. How can I debug this?

- edit:
  This post is being closed as being a duplicate, but the "This question already has answers here: " is about total different things. One is about security issue, and the other is about a Slow Python Expression warning. My question is about a driver not working at all.

Comment: Can you include a small blend file in your question that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) Or at least a screenshot of the driver editor showing all of the settings?

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/195034/42221) answer your question?

Comment: I wanted to vote to reopen, but sometimes it's easier to swim with the current so I added another answer to one of the parents as well. Though I think I will be linking to this page on other related questions. BTW I didn't know the duplicte can point to multiple answers...

Comment: Hi, clankill3r if it's any help, the expression works fine if I paste it into the X position of a cube.  Are you absolutely sure this isn't a permissions problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TLDR

Either:

- Replace `%` with `fmod` for a simple (**FAST**) expression:

```py
radians(abs(fmod(frame+45, 90) -45))
```

- Replace `abs` with `fabs` for a Python (**SLOW**) expression:

```py
radians(fabs((frame+45) % 90 - 45))
```

(In both cases I added `radians`, because that's probably what you actually intended)

### Blender fails to parse the driver expression

When you try your driver: `abs(((frame+45) % 90)-45)`, Blender first tries to [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) it using its *simple evaluator*. You can read about it in the Blender docs:

[Drivers Panel > Simple Expressions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#simple-expressions)

Source code: [source/blender/blenlib/intern/expr_pylike_eval.c](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/blenlib/intern/expr_pylike_eval.c)

**Notice there's no `%` operator** listed in the documentation (or *binary modulo* opcode in the code), Blender detects it and falls back to allow the expression to be run by much more powerful Python interpreter.

### 'Slow expression' (Python code) deemed unsafe

Since Python is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), its code can do everything, including formatting your hard drive (and worse!). To protect against malicious code in .blend files downloaded from the Internet, Blender checks all names and opcodes (basically operators) used against a [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) of things that are definitely safe:

**names**:

- builtins (basic): `all`, `any`, `len`;
- builtins (numeric): `max`, `min`, `pow`, `round`, `sum`;
- types: `bool`, `float`, `int`;
- from `bl_math` module: `clamp`, `lerp`, `smoothstep`,

**Additionally, all functions from `math` module are added**:
`acos`, `acosh`, `asin`, `asinh`, `atan`, `atan2`, `atanh`, `ceil`, `copysign`, `cos`, `cosh`, `degrees`, `dist`, `erf`, `erfc`, `exp`, `expm1`, `fabs`, `factorial`, `floor`, `fmod`, `frexp`, `fsum`, `gamma`, `gcd`, `hypot`, `isclose`, `isfinite`, `isinf`, `isnan`, `isqrt`, `lcm`, `ldexp`, `lgamma`, `log`, `log1p`, `log10`, `log2`, `modf`, `pow`, `radians`, `remainder`, `sin`, `sinh`, `sqrt`, `tan`, `tanh`, `trunc`, `prod`, `perm`, `comb`, `nextafter`, `ulp`

**opcodes**:

- **unary operators**: `+`, `-`, `not`, `~` (`UNARY_POSITIVE`, `UNARY_NEGATIVE`, `UNARY_NOT`, `UNARY_INVERT`);
- **binary operators**: `@`, `**`, `*`, `%`, `+`, `-`, `[x]`(subscription operator), `//`, `/`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|` (`BINARY_MATRIX_MULTIPLY`, `BINARY_POWER`, `BINARY_MULTIPLY`, `BINARY_MODULO`, `BINARY_ADD`, `BINARY_SUBTRACT`, `BINARY_SUBSCR`, `BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE`, `BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE`,     `BINARY_LSHIFT`, `BINARY_RSHIFT`, `BINARY_AND`, `BINARY_XOR`, `BINARY_OR`);
- **comparison operators**: `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=` (`COMPARE_OP(<)`, `COMPARE_OP(<=)` etc.);
- **collection constructors**: `(1, 2)`, `[1, 2]`, `{1, 2}`, `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` (`BUILD_TUPLE`, `BUILD_LIST`, `BUILD_SET`, `BUILD_MAP`);
- **ternary conditional operator**: `a if c else b` (`POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`, `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE`);

As well as some low-level opcodes you probably don't need to know:

> **inplace** versions of the binary operators - **not** assignment operators! (`INPLACE_MATRIX_MULTIPLY`, `INPLACE_FLOOR_DIVIDE`, `INPLACE_TRUE_DIVIDE`, `INPLACE_ADD`, `INPLACE_SUBTRACT`, `INPLACE_MULTIPLY`, `INPLACE_MODULO`, `INPLACE_POWER`, `INPLACE_LSHIFT`, `INPLACE_RSHIFT`, `INPLACE_AND`, `INPLACE_XOR`, `INPLACE_OR`);
>  **stack management** opcodes: `POP_TOP`, `ROT_TWO`, `ROT_THREE`, `DUP_TOP`, `DUP_TOP_TWO`, `NOP`;
>  **code flow opcodes**: `RETURN_VALUE`, `JUMP_FORWARD`, `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP`, `JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP`, `JUMP_ABSOLUTE`;
>  **other low level opcodes**: `LOAD_GLOBAL`, `LOAD_FAST`, `STORE_FAST`, `DELETE_FAST`, `LOAD_DEREF`, `STORE_DEREF`;
>  **"special cases"** (which qualifies really as the same as previous group, but could be dangerous without additional checks done in the Blender code): `LOAD_CONST`, `LOAD_NAME`, `CALL_FUNCTION`, `CALL_FUNCTION_KW`, `CALL_FUNCTION_EX`,

Source code: [source/blender/python/intern/bpy_driver.c](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_driver.c#L345)

**Notice there's no `abs` name**, so your driver won't pass the security check!

### Problem summary

You can see the result in the console (*Window > Toggle System Console*)

```
BPY_driver_eval() - restricted access disallows name 'abs', enable auto-execution to support
```

If your code had only `abs` name without `%` operator, it would parse as a simple expression. If it would have only `%` without `abs`, it would fail to parse as a simple expression, but would be allowed as a *Slow Expression*: [image].

However your code first fails to be parsed as a simple expression due to unsupported `%` operator, and then fails again at the security check due to `abs` name not being on a slow expression whitelist.

### The solution

Having both `%` and `abs` forces you to either disable the security checks, as suggested by Chris - you should read about the security considerations here:

[How to randomize any value every frame between specific interval?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243271/60486)

Or alternatively you can redesign your formula, which in this case is trivial:

- first you should consider if you can satisfy the fast expression requirements, by replacing your `%` operator. Most of the time* `a % x` works exactly the same as `fmod(a, x)`, therefore the fix is trivial: instead of `abs(((frame+45) % 90)-45)` do `abs(fmod(frame+45, 90)-45)`.
- if you can't make the simple expression, forget about all of its requirements altogether, and focus on the slow expression requirements written directly in this post. It's probably a mistake that `abs` is not allowed and I'll suggest a change. However, **there's `fabs` available**.

### Side notes

Chris noticed how the values you use are typical angles expressed in degrees, and yet inside drivers (or any other form of scripting) the angle values are interpreted as radians. Therefore what you probably want is `radians(value_expressed_in_degrees)` to convert the degrees to radians.

If operands (dividend and divisor) have different signs, **fmod and modulo operator `%` will produce different results!** The fix is to replace `a % n` not with `fmod(a, n)` but with `fmod(fmod(a, n)+n, n)`:

[How to replicate `%` operator in simple driver expressions?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277837/60486)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136390/discussion-on-answer-by-markus-von-broady-driver-not-working).

Comment: Gorgious made a list about the [elevated superset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309782/60486) of available driver names so I thought it might be useful to link it here.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have this checked: "Auto run python scripts" in your preferences.

[image]

Note: i assume you want to drive a rotation? be aware that you have to work with radians, not degrees, so just change your formula so that it calculates in radians, then it should work

Comment: It's a driver.  You don't need to do that for drivers.

Comment: and again, Marty you are wrong. Just try it out, read the logging and you will see: Error in Driver: The following Python expression failed:
 'abs(((frame+45) % 90)-45)'

 BPY_driver_eval() - restricted access disallows name 'abs', enable auto-execution to support

Comment: i just wonder who upvotes your wrong (again and again) comments....

Comment: @MartyFouts: Please, open up a new blend file where auto run is off, then copy his statement in the driver of rotation -> you will get that error and the driver won't work. But...after checking and then it works, i have to admit, if i uncheck the auto run, it still works. i have no idea why. i tested with 3.3. alpha

Comment: I am the one who upvoted, because i genuinely though I had this very option disabled at all times myself and didn't encountered the issue. This discussion doesn't need to get personal, doesn't it? Though now I am even more confused because, this expression was working on my side before i restarted Blender, but now it says it's an invalid expression...

Comment: and if you uncheck...it still works...it is confusing! but you have to check it once that it works....weird. But i am glad you experience the same...i tried it now for the 5th time....just to. make sure i am not completely stupid.

Comment: in general Marty is right...of course. You don't have to check that for "normal" drivers. But looks like "abs" is something special.

Comment: i noticed [Drivers Panel &mdash; Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#drivers-simple-expressions) doesn't mention the availability of modulo operator... Which is odd because I am pretty sure I used it before, and the fact is that it worked between some of the new Blender instances

Comment: I was AFK, but this is weird because [Scripting and Security](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/security.html) mentions drivers in passing, but in a way that implies that either _all_ or _no_ driver should have this problem.  There is no mention of a restricted name list.  [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195038/42221) shows we're not the only people who are confused.  I can't find any reference to a restricted list in a search either. So it seems my original comment needs a clarification but nobody knows what that clarification is.

Comment: To add to the confusion, [this answer] claims, correctly, that it is the `%` operator that is restricted not `abs` despite what the error message says.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the discussion in the comments of the two existing answers:

There are two approaches you can take:

- You can follow the recommendation in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263870/42221) and enable *Auto-Run*. But that produces a different problem: you've decreased the security of your Blender usage because now anytime you download a Blender file and open it your vulnerable to Python scripting attacks.
- You can follow the recommendation in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263879/42221), ignore the actual text of the error message, and find a scripted expression that doesn't trigger the warning. But that's not well documented and as you can see by the confusion in the comments might not be easy to do.

I would recommend, and have upvoted the second answer, ie, use `radians(abs(fmod(frame+45, 90) -45))` in your driver to avoid the error.  But I would not be honest if I did not admit that most Blender users never see this kind of problem simply because we ignore the security implication and enable auto-run.

You have to decide how much security risk you are willing to tolerate.  Select one of those two approaches, *accept* that answer, and good luck.