# Custom Property Driver - How would I convert a linear value to an exponential one?

Tags: drivers

I hope I can explain my issue correctly here. I'm rigging the objects in the video below - a Center Ring, a Piston, and an Outer "Fan Blade" piece. I have put a driver on both of the moving parts which means that the start and end values work, and the piston (with object contraints to follow both) lines up correctly.

However, because the piston is on a rotating wheel, the movement on the blade is not linear. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Video of the Moving Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ei2vk4BXY)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, multiplying the expression by the variable again solved the issue perfectly. Going from (radians(var) * 40) to (radians(var) * var * 40)

I think this may only have worked because the variable I'm using to drive the animation is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `pow` function like so: `radians(pow(var, 2)) * 40`, where `2` is the chosen exponent:
$$x^0 = 1$$
$$x^1 = x$$
$$x^2 = x × x$$
$$x^3 = x × x × x$$

$x^3 < x^2 < x^1 < x^0$     for $0 < x < 1$

$x^0 < x^1 < x^2 < x^3$     for $x > 1$

By using an exponent rather than multiplying by self, you have more control on the falloff, because an exponent doesn't have to be an integer:

[image]

To see a list of all driver functions, you can take a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263879/60486).